# Youtube video playable using the default embed, but not playable with the youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have some YT videos to play in the VB Webbrowser, but playing it gives me the 'This video contains content from VEVO. It is restricted from playback on certain sites or applications' error. But when I try playing it using the default embed code provided in the Youtube link itself it plays perfectly. Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

On the custom HTML page made, this is the code I used

```
function main(vidid)
  {
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '200',
      width: '300',
      playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                enablejsapi : 1,
                origin: "https://www.youtube.com",
                vq: 'medium'},
      videoId: vidid,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing, or is the video just blocked for API users? My apologies if my question is too bad.

Comment: You trying to spam us with a "RickAstley" spamvid !!!!!!!   Just so you know, I tested in all ways and it works. You can play here if you like http://www.myonlinelocation.com/YouTube_Play/

Comment: Sorry, haha.Could it be a problem with the Visual Studio webbrowser?

Answer (score 1):

Found the source of the problem. Turns out that I was hosting the webpage on PC, which Youtube doesn't allow. After I uploaded my html page to a web server, it works perfectly.